# Provider org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

Tags: java, spring, session, jaxb

I am facing following exception when I am running a batch job wherein I am making a webservice call and getting the xml response.

JAXBContext.newInstance("somewsdl");

[Exception [EclipseLink-50000] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): **org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException**
Exception Description:

> The context path "wsdl class" contains no ObjectFactory or jaxb.index,
>   no external metadata was found in properties Map, and sessions.xml was
>   found or was invalid.

Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7095] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description:

> The sessions.xml resource [sessions.xml] was not found on the resource
>   path.  Check that the resource name/path and classloader passed to the
>   SessionManager.getSession are correct.  The sessions.xml should be
>   included in the root of the application's deployed jar, if the
>   sessions.xml is deployed in a sub-directory in the application's jar
>   ensure that the correct resource path using "/" not "\" is used.]
>
> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider
>   org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory could not be
>   instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

- with linked exception:
  [Exception [EclipseLink-50000] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException

I am using web logic 1221.1.I am getting this error when I am upgrading my spring to 4.3.3 and quartz version is 2.2.3